# Find all natural $e$ for which there is $f$, with $e>f$, such that there is a polyhedron with $e$ vertices and $f$ faces

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Find all natural numbers $e$ to which there exists a natural number $f$ with $e>f$ such that there exists a polyhedron with $e$ vertices and $f$ faces.

This is an old MO problem, but I'm stuck. Euler's polyhedral theorem $V+F-E=2$ gave no immediate results. My first thought was to just choose $F$ accordingly, but this would be too easy. I'd appreciate help.

Comment: See whether [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654075/possible-edge-counts-in-polyhedra) helps you.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the MO problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply consider an n-gonal pyramid with one of its base vertices being truncated. For that one you have V = (vertices = Ecken, e) = (n + 1) - 1 + 3 = n+3 and F = (faces = Flächen, f) = (n + 1) + 1 = n+2. Thus you would have V > F, as desired, for any valid n.

The smallest base of a pyramid is a triangle, thus n is greater or equal to 3. And therefore you derive that V greater or equal to 6 would be as required.

Thus you only would have to check smaller numbers in addition. The only polyhedron with 4 vertices is the tetrahedron. That one has 4 faces too. So V = 4 disqualifies, as it does not pass the requirement V > F.

Finally assume there would be a solution with V = 5. As V > F (and F > 3) this clearly results in F = 4. But by duality the only polyhedron with 4 faces is the tetrahedron again and so V = 4, in contradiction to the assumption of V = 5. Therefore V = 5 disqualifies as well.

And so you are done with the final result V > 5.

--- rk

Comment: Coincidence or not this is a German MO problem, from the 9th Grade, second round of the 40th MO.